# Everything tearing other than background image with 3 monitors

Tags: graphics, multi-monitor, monitors, hdmi

So here is my problem:
[image]
[image]

**System Info**
[image]

**Displays**

```
-Display-
Resolution      : 9600x2160 pixels
Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
Version     : 1.18.4
-Monitors-
Monitor 0       : 1920x1080 pixels
Monitor 1       : 3840x2160 pixels
Monitor 2       : 3840x2160 pixels
-Extensions-
BIG-REQUESTS
Composite
DAMAGE
DOUBLE-BUFFER
DPMS
DRI2
GLX
Generic Event Extension
MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
MIT-SHM
Present
RANDR
RECORD
RENDER
SECURITY
SGI-GLX
SHAPE
SYNC
X-Resource
XC-MISC
XFIXES
XFree86-DGA
XFree86-VidModeExtension
XINERAMA
XInputExtension
XKEYBOARD
XTEST
XVideo
-OpenGL-
Vendor      : Intel Open Source Technology Center
Renderer        : Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
Version     : 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4
Direct Rendering        : Yes
```

With 2 monitors there is no problem.
When I use Mate there is no problem.
I believe this must be a software issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you run with 2 monitors, is it the 2 3840x2160 pixels monitors? or can you run 2 monitors and have mixed display size?

Comment: Answers in answers please  and comments in comments.

Comment: Good point, its 1 large and 1 smaller monitor. I will experiment tomorrow.